# Inductor in an AC circuit

Tags: electromagnetism

In an AC circuit with just an inductor, current that lags behind the EMF.

I am assuming this emf is self induced in inductor.Is that correct.?

what about the source EMF. Source EMF will always be in phase with current.? Is that correct.?

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what your asking.  If you're thinking about an (ideal) inductor connected across a sinusoidal voltage source,  the voltage across the source and inductor are *identical*.  Now, the voltage across an inductor is proportional the rate of change of current through

$$v_L(t) = L \frac{di_L}{dt}$$

For the case you describe (as best as I can tell)

$$v_L(t) = v_S(t) = V_S\cos(\omega t)$$

It follows that the inductor current *must* be

$$i_L(t) = \frac{V_S}{\omega L}\sin(\omega t) = \frac{V_S}{\omega L}\cos\left(\omega t - \frac{\pi}{2}\right)$$

and so the current through the inductor 'lags' the voltage across the inductor *as well as* the source.